# Import error when running python script inside docker container?

Tags: python, docker, import, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I am aiming to start a script that consume rabbitmq massages inside a container, here is the important details:

`messenger.py`,which is the script I am trying to run:

```
import pika
from . import create_app

class PikaMassenger():

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def consume(self, keys, callback):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return self


    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.conn.close()



def start_consumer(app):

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        try:
            print("Event recieved %r" % body)
            with app.app_context():
                pass

        except Exception as e:
            print("Consuming event %s failed: %s" % (method.routing_key, str(e)))

    with PikaMassenger() as consumer:
        consumer.consume(keys=['user.*', ], callback=callback)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    start_consumer(app)
```

My `__init__.py` simply contains the app factory(`create_app`). My Dockerfile and docker-compose are:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM  python:3.6

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENV SECRET_KEY dev


ENV FLASK_APP run.py

CMD  flask run
```

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```
  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
    expose:
      - "5000"
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    restart: on-failure

  app_consumer:
    build:
      context: ./app
    command: python -m messenger.py
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
```

So what I am trying to do is to run two containers with the same `Dockerfile`, while overriding the `command` parameter in one of them, I am aware that given the above details, error will occure:

```
 File "/app/massenger.py", line 2, in <module>
     from . import create_app
 ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Perhaps I may have to change the working directory in `docker-compose.yaml`, or run my script in different way.

Please inform me if further details are needed, or if you want me to try something.

Comment: whatever create_app is, it's not in the same directory as messenger.py. If it's installed through requirements.txt, just import it directly. If it's something you wrote, then you need to fix the path to the script inside the container.

Comment: no it is in the same directory, it is in __init__.py.

Comment: This may help: https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent

Comment: `from . import create_app` would require this function to be defined inside `__init.py__` or, within `__init.py__` you would need something along the lines `from .mymodule import create_app`. Is that the case?

Comment: sure it is in __init.py__, I think I made that clear in the question.

Comment: The error shows the path of the file as under auth ( /auth/massenger.py ) , is there a auth folder on the root ?

Comment: It is the same as app, I switched auth directory to app in the question for simplification only.

Comment: I have edited the question @SoumenMukherjee , please inform if anything is ambiguous.

Comment: Did you try without the '-m' option ?

Comment: yes I tried that, but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error occurred because of the '.' representing the path is wrong . In local '.' adopts to the current directory .But in Docker '.' gets the path from the some root directories.

Try to give that path as static path or use the os.getcwd() method.